# Opening EDGE Chromium using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, chromium

In order to perform the testing I have to open the Chromium Browser. But When i use

```
driver = webdriver.Edge('msedgedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://xxx.service-now.com/')
```

it is taking me to the sign-in page.

But when i normally open 'xxx.service-now.com' it takes windows authentication and takes me to the service-now page directly.

This is my normal Chromium Window
[image: This is my normal Chromium Window]

and this is my Chromium Window when i am opening using Selenium
[image: Chromium Window when i am opening using Selenium]

I want to open the normal Chromium using selenium, as it will automatically sign me in.

Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some experiments i got the answer.

```
import selenium, getpass
from selenium import webdriver 
from msedge.selenium_tools import Edge, EdgeOptions

user = getpass.getuser()

options = EdgeOptions()
options.use_chromium = True
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\" + user + "\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Edge\\User Data")
driver = Edge('msedgedriver.exe',options = options)
driver.get('https://xxx.service-now.com/')
```

This has resolved my issue.